# How do I escape an "@" character in a Thymeleaf link tag?

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

Here is my link:

```
<link th:href="@{/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css}"
      href="../../static/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The folder starts with an "@" symbol.  (My IDE, IntelliJ Idea, raises an error on this.)

**Update:**

I also tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<link th:with="linkString = '/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'" th:href="@{linkString}"
      href="../static/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The dev console in this case reads:

`index:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/linkString' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

If I change the folder name and remove the "@", the problem goes away and the CSS appears on the page.

Comment: A late reply, I know, but I was not able to recreate the issue. I have a link tag containing `th:href="@{css/@foo/bar.css}"` which behaves normally: the CSS is used on the page. It actually breaks (css is no longer found) if I use the Thymeleaf escape character \ (backslash) to escape the `@` in `@foo`.

Comment: Interesting, have you tried that exact link from fortawesome?  IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate still highlights this as an error in version 2020.3 (if you mouse-over the `@` symbol). I still see the message in the dev console.

Comment: I have not downloaded the Fort Awesome materials (needs a free trial sign-up, as far as I can tell). But I did notice that when trying to create a resources folder called `@whatever` in my IDE (NetBeans in this specific case) the IDE threw an error and refused to create the folder. But when I created the same folder in the same place via the OS (Windows) outside of the IDE, then the IDE had no problem using the folder. And Thymeleaf had no problem using it, either.

Comment: Ok, I’m adding the question tag for IDEA in case it turns out to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your link address in a `string` variable and pass it on your page. and in html try like below.

```html
 <link th:href="@{'/' + ${page}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not so desirable.  You'd be breaking a separation of concerns doing this.  (For example, a UI designer would now have to modify server-side code to correct a CSS path.)

Answer (score 0):

This still seems to be the result in IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3.  My workaround thus far is to manually copy the files to a folder without the `@` symbol as in:

```
<link th:href="@{/lib/fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css}"
      href="../static/lib/fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```